# What is the point of a private pure virtual function?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, non-virtual-interface

I came across the following code in a header file:

```
class Engine
{
public:
    void SetState( int var, bool val );
    {   SetStateBool( int var, bool val ); }

    void SetState( int var, int val );
    {   SetStateInt( int var, int val ); }
private:
    virtual void SetStateBool(int var, bool val ) = 0;    
    virtual void SetStateInt(int var, int val ) = 0;    
};
```

To me, this implies that either the `Engine` class or a class derived from it, has to provide the implementation for those pure virtual functions. But I didn't think derived classes could have access to those private functions in order to reimplement them - so why make them virtual?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The question in the topic suggest a pretty common confusion. The confusion is common enough, that [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/) advocated against using private virtuals, for a long time, because confusion seemed to be a bad thing.

So to get rid of the confusion first: Yes, private virtual functions can be overridden in the derived classes. Methods of derived classes can't call virtual functions from the base class, but they can provide their own implementation for them. According to Herb Sutter, having public non-virtual interface in the base class and a private implementation that can be customized in the derived classes, allows for better "separation of the specification of interface from the specification of the implementation's customizable behavior". You can read more about it in his article ["Virtuality"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

There is however one more interesting thing in the code you presented, that deserves some more attention, in my opinion. The public interface consists of a set of overloaded non-virtual functions and those functions call non-public, non-overloaded virtual functions. As usual in the C++ world it is an idiom, it has a name and of course it is useful. The name is (surprise, surprise!)

"Public Overloaded Non-Virtuals Call Protected Non-Overloaded Virtuals"

It helps to [properly manage the hiding rule](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.9). You can read more about it [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.3), but I'll try to explain it shortly.

Imagine, that virtual functions of the `Engine` class are also its interface and it is a set of overloaded functions that is not pure virtual. If they were pure virtual, one could still encounter the same problem, as described below, but lower in the class hierarchy.

```
class Engine
{
public:
    virtual void SetState( int var, bool val ) {/*some implementation*/}
    virtual void SetState( int var, int val )  {/*some implementation*/}
};
```

Now let's assume you want to create a derived class and you need to provide a new implementation only for the method, that takes two ints as arguments.

```
class MyTurbochargedV8 : public Engine
{
public:
    // To prevent SetState( int var, bool val ) from the base class,
    // from being hidden by the new implementation of the other overload (below),
    // you have to put using declaration in the derived class
    using Engine::SetState;

    void SetState( int var, int val )  {/*new implementation*/}
};
```

If you forgot to put the using declaration in the derived class (or to redefine the second overload), you could get in trouble in the scenario below.

```
MyTurbochargedV8* myV8 = new MyTurbochargedV8();
myV8->SetState(5, true);
```

If you didn't prevent the hiding of the `Engine` members, the statement:

```
myV8->SetState(5, true);
```

would call `void SetState( int var, int val )` from the derived class, converting `true` to `int`.

If the interface is not virtual and the virtual implementation is non-public, like in your exmaple, the author of the derived class has one less problem to think about and can simply write

```
class MyTurbochargedV8 : public Engine
{
private:
    void SetStateInt(int var, int val )  {/*new implementation*/}
};
```

Comment: why does the virtual function have to be private? Can it be public?

Comment: I wonder if guidelines given by Herb Sutter in his "Virtuality" article still holds today ?

Comment: @Rich You could, but by making them non-public, you can convey their intent more clearly.  First, it shows a separation of concerns if you stick to making the interface public and the implementation non-public.  Second, if you want inheriting classes to be able to call the base implementations, you can declare them protected; if you only want them to provide their own implementations without calling into the base ones, you make them private.

Answer (score 45):

*Private pure virtual* function is the base of the **Non-virtual interface** idiom (OK, it's not absolutely always *pure* virtual, but still virtual there). Of course, this is used for other things, too, but I find this for most useful (: In two words:  in a public function, you could put some common things (such as logging, statistics, etc.) in the beginning and in the end of the function and then, "in the middle" to call this private virtual function, that will be different for the specific derived class. Something like:

```
class Base
{
    // ..
public:
    void f();
private:
    virtual void DerivedClassSpecific() = 0;
   // ..
};
void Base::f()
{
    //.. Do some common stuff
    DerivedClassSpecific();
    //.. Some other common stuff
}
// ..

class Derived: public Base
{
    // ..
private:
    virtual void DerivedClassSpecific();
    //..
};
void Derived::DerivedClassSpecific()
{
    // ..
}
```

*Pure virtual* - just obligates the derived classes to implement it.

**EDIT**: More about this: [Wikipedia::NVI-idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface)

Answer (score 17):

Well, for one, this would allow a derived class to implement a function that the base class (containing the pure virtual function declaration) can call.

Comment: that **only** the base class can call!

Comment: @underscore_d Every derived class implementing the function (and its friends) can call its own function. (Such call will be virtually dispatched, unless explicitly qualified.)

Comment: @PabloH Right! If a derived class provides its own override, it can call that (whether or not its override is private). A derived class only can't call the function if it was private in the base, and the derived class doesn't override it. Which seems obvious. I'm not sure what my point was meant to be, back in 2016 :-)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: Clarified statements about ability to override and ability to access/invoke.**

It will be able to override those private functions.  For example, the following contrived example works (**EDIT: made derived class method private, and drop the derived class method invocation in `main()` to better demonstrate the intent of design pattern in use.**):

```
#include <iostream>

class Engine
{
public:
  void SetState( int var, bool val )
  {
    SetStateBool( var, val );
  }

  void SetState( int var, int val )
  {
    SetStateInt( var, val );
  }

private:

    virtual void SetStateBool(int var, bool val ) = 0;
    virtual void SetStateInt(int var, int val ) = 0;

};

class DerivedEngine : public Engine
{
private:
  virtual void SetStateBool(int var, bool val )
  {
    std::cout << "DerivedEngine::SetStateBool() called" << std::endl;
  }

  virtual void SetStateInt(int var, int val )
  {
    std::cout << "DerivedEngine::SetStateInt() called" << std::endl;
  }
};


int main()
{
  DerivedEngine e;
  Engine * be = &e;

  be->SetState(4, true);
  be->SetState(2, 1000);
}
```

`Private` `virtual` methods in a base class like the ones in your code are typically used to implement the [Template Method design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).  That design pattern allows one to change the behavior of an algorithm in the base class without changing the code in the base class.   The above code where the base class methods are invoked through a base class pointer is a simple example of the Template Method pattern.

Comment: I see, but if derived classes have a sort of access anyway, why bother making them private?

Comment: @BeeBand: The user would have access to the public derived class virtual method overrides, but wouldn't have access to the base class ones.  The derived class author in this case could keep the virtual method overrides private as well.  In fact I'll make the change in the sample code above to emphasize that.  Either way, they could always inherit publically and override the private base class virtual methods, but they'd still only have access to their own derived class virtual methods.  Note that I'm making a distinction beteween override and access/invocation.

Comment: because you're wrong. the inheritance visibility between classes `Engine` and `DerivedEngine` has nothing to do with what `DerivedEngine` can or can't override (or access, for that matter).

Comment: @wilhelmtell: *sigh*  You are of course correct.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Private virtual method is used for limiting the number of derived classes that can override the given function. The derived classes that has to override the private virtual method will have to be a friend of the base class.

A brief explanation can be found of [DevX.com](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14995).

---

**EDIT** A private virtual method is effectively used in [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). The derived classes can override the private virtual method but the derived classes cannot call it's base class private virtual method (in your example, `SetStateBool` and `SetStateInt`). Only the base class can effectively call its private virtual method (**Only if derived classes need to invoke the base implementation of a virtual function, make the virtual function protected**).

An interesting article can be found about [**Virtuality**](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm).

Comment: @Gentleman... hmmm scroll down to Colin D Bennett's comment. He seems to think that "A private virtual function can be
overridden by derived classes, but can only be called from within the base class.". @Michael Goldshteyn also thinks like that too.

Comment: I guess you've forgotten the principle that a private based class cannot be seen by its derived class. That is the OOP rules and it applies on all language that is OOP. In order for a derived class to implement its base class private virtual method, it has to be a `friend` of the base class. Qt has taken the same approach when they implemented their XML DOM document model.

Comment: @Gentleman: No, I haven't forgotten. I made a typo in my comment. Instead of "access to the base class methods" I should have wrote "can override the base class methods". The derived class can certainly override the private virtual base class method even if it cannot access that base class method. The DevX.com article you pointed out was incorrect (public inheritance). Try out the code in my answer. Despite the private virtual base class method, the derived class is able to override it. Let's not confuse the ability to override a private virtual base class method with the ability to invoke it.

Comment: @Gentleman: @wilhelmtell pointed out the error in my answer/comment.  My claim about inheritance affecting derived class accessibility of the base class method was off.  I've removed the offending comment to your answer.

Comment: @Void, I see that a derived class **can** override its base class private virtual method but it cannot use it. So, this is essentially a Template Method pattern.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR answer:

You can treat it like another level of encapsulation - somewhere between **protected** and **private**: you can't call it from child class, but you can override it.

It is useful when implementing [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern. You could use **protected**, but **private** together with **virtual** may be considered as better choice, because of better encapsulation.