# Force a programmer to invoke a method in its Base

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I built an Async task service executor that execute tasks by external request.

Each task contains the function void `run(),` so any programmer who want's to add a task to the system needs to inherit From `BaseTask`.

```
    interface ITask{
       void run();
    }
    abstract BaseTask : ITask{
       //force "run()" to set Result
       public ResultContainer Result {set; get;}
       void run();
    }

    class SomeTask : BaseTask {
       void run(){
           ////run the operation here, in the end, set the result.
           //force the programmer to set the Result;
           this.Result = new ResultContainer("task ok");
       }
    }
```

For internal reasons, the `run()` must be void.

Is there any way that I can force a programmer who wants to add a task to invoke `Result` in `BaseTask` and set its value? 
**Do you think it is a bad practice?**

Thanks

Comment: You could add another method to ITask and BaseTask for onResult() with the implementation to set result but regardless relying on someone else to do what you want them to do is probably not reliable :)

Comment: This seems related: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is something to be avoided. Rules like this should be in place such that they're enforced by the compiler (rather than convention) when possible and practical.

In your case, you should do something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseTask
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Result = RunInternal();
    }

    public ResultContainer Result { get; set; }

    protected abstract ResultContainer RunInternal();
}
```

This will accomplish what you want semantically (that invoking the `Run` function externally will always cause the `Result` property to be set), and it forces the developer who inherits from `BaseTask` to supply the value that's being used. The only difference is that they will override (or, rather, implement) the `RunInternal` function instead of `Run`.

Comment: just perfect! simple and clean, I have nothing more to say

Comment: `BaseTask.Run` needs to be `sealed`?

Comment: @HemalPandya: In C#, all methods are sealed unless marked with `virtual`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this fits some pre-imagined design pattern, but could you add another method to `BaseTask` that does have a return value,a nd have the developers implement that? For example (sorry if the code isn't 100% correct, not doing this in VS):

```
interface ITask{
   void run();
}

abstract BaseTask : ITask{
   //force "run()" to set Result
   public ResultContainer Result{set;get;}

   void run() {
       Result = runInternal();
   }

   protected abstract ResultContainer runInternal();

}

class SomeTask : BaseTask {
   protected override ResultContainer runInternal(){
       return new ResultContainer("task ok");
   }
}
```

Comment: Its an old C++ idiom -- used to be called `public non-virtual function calling private pure virtual function`...or something similar. The overriding `<strike>function</strike> method` now needs to `protected`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970279/what-is-the-point-of-a-private-pure-virtual-function