# C++: Avoiding repetition by calling pure virtual function

Tags: c++

For the following code,

```
class A
{
    private:
        virtual void f() = 0;
        virtual void g() = 0;
        ...

    public:
        A()
        {
        }

        ...
}

class B : public A
{
    private:
        void f()
        {
            ...
        }
        void g()
        {
            ...
        }
        void h()
        {
            if (...)
            {
                f();
            }
            else
            {
                g();
            }
        }

        ...

    public:
        B()
        {
            h();
        }

        ...

}


class C : public A
{
    private:
        void f()
        {
            ...
        }
        void g()
        {
            f();
        }
        void h()
        {
            if (...)
            {
                f();
            }
            else
            {
                g();
            }
        }

        ...

    public:
        C()
        {
            h();
        }

        ...

}
```

is there a way to avoid repetition of h() (the context of function h() in both classes B and C is the same) or we cannot avoid it simply because we cannot call pure virtual functions in constructors?

Comment: You really want `private` f and g?

Comment: it is an example from textbook, does it matter in the context of my question?

Comment: This is a very vague question, and your constructor setup isn't quite right. Also if you create a private pure virtual function then it cannot be instantiated NOR can any of its child classes.

Comment: @AhmedMasud: Oh yes, it can. That had me astounded too.

Comment: To your question: Yes, that's one of the main uses of `virtual`.

Comment: It works, just give it a spin in the compiler of your choice.

Comment: For the private virtual, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3978552/2077394
For the question on h, just put it in the base class if it is common?

Comment: @Joky: Nice find, didn't have such handy myself.

Comment: won't it cause "pure virtual function call" error if i put it in the base class since i call it in constructors of derived classes?

Comment: btw it is a textbook in turkish about oop

Comment: The order of construction is base first and derived after. Moreover h does not need to be virtual, does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement your function `h()` as a member of `A`.

The pure virtual function call would only be an issue if `h()` gets executed during the body of `A::A()` (or other `A` constructors or `A::~A()`).  Inside the body of `B::B()` or `C::C()`, the polymorphic type of `*this` is `B` or `C` respectively, so your virtual overrides declared in class `B` or `C` will have effect.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, add an intermediate class D which only implements that function and inherits from A. Then B and C can inherit from D.

Comment: won't it cause "pure virtual function call" error since i call it in constructors of B and C?