# Is friend function getting inherited here?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, private, encapsulation

The method `fun()` in the Derived class is private. When we call the function `ptr->fun()` through run time polymorphism, it is executing.
But this violates the encapsulation property of the Derived class.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Derived;

class Base {
private:
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base Fun"; }
friend int main();
};

class Derived: public Base {
private:
    void fun() { cout << "Derived Fun"; }
};

int main()
{
Base *ptr = new Derived;
ptr->fun();
return 0;
}
```

Can anyone please explain what is happening?

Comment: friends have acces to private members. You declare the main as friend, so there is access to private members. (why you did this is a miracle to me)

Comment: @tobi303, friend has access to private of `Base` not `Derived` and the `fun()` being called when the program is run is `fun()` of the `Derived` class.. BTW i was playing around with c++ concepts, so came across this.. nothing practical..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `Derived::fun()` is also `virtual`, because if a function in a derived class has the same declaration as a virtual function in the base class, the function in derived class automatically gets `virtual`, even if that was not explicitly specified.

Secondly, it is completely OK to access private virtual functions via public intermediate functions from the base class, see, for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978552/3216312) and its links, particularly [Virtuality by Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm). A sample code might be like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Derived;

class Base {
private:
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base Fun"; }
public:
    void funInt() { fun(); }
};

class Derived: public Base {
private:
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Derived Fun"; }
};

int main()
{
Base *ptr = new Derived;
ptr->funInt();
return 0;
}
```

So, what happens in your case, I think, is a similar situation: the `main` is allowed to access `ptr->fun()`, but due to virtuality this `fun()` happens to be `Derived::fun()`.

**UPD**: expanding on a comment

> But doesn't this sound a little alarming.. I mean, all the functions
>   that derive from the Base class, will have their private members
>   accessible to the friend functions of the Base class

No, not all the functions of `Derived` will be accessible to the friends of `Base`, but only those that can be accessible via `Base` pointer. For example:

```
class Base { 
    virtual void fun();
    friend int main(); 
}
class Derived: public Base {
    virtual void fun();
    virtual void foo();
    void bar();
}
```

only `Derived::fun()` can be accessed from main:

```
int main() {
    Derived *ptr = new Derived;
    Base* baseptr = ptr;
    baseptr->fun(); // ok, calls Derived::fun()
    baseptr->foo(); // error, no such function in Base
    ptr->foo(); // error, foo is private
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `virtual` function are intentionally extensible, and any override of `virtual` function in `Derived` means that that function can be called via `Base` pointer; this is the main purpose of `virtual` functions. If `Derived` makes its overriding function `private`, it still should be conscious that the function can be accessed via `Base` pointer, because that is the main idea behind the `virtual` functions.

Comment: ook. But doesn't this sound a little alarming.. I mean, all the functions that derive from the `Base` class, will have their private members accessible to the friend functions of the `Base` class.

Comment: @haris, no! Only the `virtual` functions that have already been there in `Base`! I will expand the answer in a minute.

Comment: @haris, expanded the answer

Comment: nice.. understood..  :)

Answer (score 1):

`Friend` functions never take part in inheritance.

**What is happening here?**
When virtual method is defined in `Base` class, a virtual table is createdwhich contains address of `fun` method of `Base` class. And since, `Derived` class inherits it, the VTABLE also contains the address of `Derived` class `fun` method. Now, since `main` is the friend function of `Base` class, compiler allows access of its members to `main` method irrespective of their access specifier. Hence, `main` gets the address of `Derived::fun` and `Derived` class `fun` gets called at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have declared `fun`as virtual.
At runtime when the vtable is searched, it finds the entry for `Derived::fun()` and hence jumps to the address.

However the friend functions does not get inherited, you can check using this.

```
class Base {
private:
    virtual void fun() { cout << "Base Fun"; }
    friend int main();
    int z = 20;
};

class Derived : public Base {
private:
    void fun() { cout << "Derived Fun"; }
    int m = 10;
};

int main()
{
    Base *ptr = new Derived;
    ptr->z = 10; //Accepted
    ptr->m = 5; //error
    return 0;
}
```

Here private member of `Derived` `m` is not accessible to main.

Comment: i didn't get you, the program is accessing the private function of Derived class from the `main()` function.. how does making `fun()` function in Base class virtual effects that..

Comment: @Nishant i doubt vtables work that way.. see this description    
http://imgur.com/6e23Roa

Comment: @DenisZaikin yes, obviously it will be "Base Fun", because ptr is pointing to object of derived, which has subobject of base.

Comment: @haris deleted my comment, it was wrongly put, what i meant to say is that since private functions can access private virtual function and in your case, just because of method is declared virtual, the Derived:Fun gets called.

As you can see in my example, not all private members can be accessed, only virtual.