# C++ Providing run-time access to a union with different (built-in) types

Tags: c++, c++17, unions

I'm working with a library that uses a C interface and several functions that pass a pointer to a struct as the output (not return).

The struct is something like

```
struct S {
    short a;
    short b;
    union {
        char cdata[5];
        short sdata[5];
        long ldata[5];
        float fdata[5];
        double dfdata[5];
    } u;
}
```

I've written some template classes that can provide access to this in the form

```
auto parameter = MyClass<double>(constructor parameters);
parameter.SetValue(5.2); // Sets u.dfdata[0] = 5.2;
// other functions for changing index, or passing in a vector, etc
```

This is nice(ish) in that it abstracts away a lot of the required knowledge about structs, and only requires the user (still me, but whatever...) to know about the type of the parameter (`double`, `float`, `long`, `short` or `char`).

However, it's a compile time construct. The hardware I'm communicating with through this library is able to provide a function that has something like:

```
// renamed and tidied for ease of reading
// I don't have the source for this function, only docs
short GetParameter(short address, short* prevAddress, short* nextAddress, 
             S* parameter, Other* info);
```

where `info` can be parsed to tell me the type of the parameter. This would, if it were not compile time and different types, allow something like

```
std::vector<??> a;
a.push_back(MyClass<double>(args));
a.push_back(MyClass<short>(args));
```

where `double` and `short` can be read from the `info` struct as a short (0 = char, 1 = short...) and the other arguments can be read from the S struct.

I can build a `std::vector<std::variant<MyClass<char>, MyClass<short>, ..., MyClass<double>>>` but then trying to work out how to use a `variant` has left me confused if this is a good idea at all.

I want to be able to store sets of different types of parameters, for example for saving a complete configuration, but at the moment I think my functions are all compile-time calculations (variations on `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, char>) { // do something with u.cdata[index] }`).

If I want to be able to create lists with a single type, I can't (as far as I can work out) have `virtual T ReadValue()` or `virtual void SetValue(T)` because I can't use templating on virtual functions, and if I template the class (as I do now) then I have different (class) types which become hard to operate on.

An ideal solution would look something like

```
using valType = std::variant<char, short, long, float, double>;
using varType = std::variant<MyClass<char>, ..., MyClass<double>>;

// Read this from some file, or whatever
auto values = std::vector<valType> { 3, 2.6f, 17.2, 1523l }; 

std::vector<varType> paramList = MyFunctionThatReadsThroughParamToNextParam();
for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    paramList[i].SetValue(values[i]);
    // where the type contained in values[i] matches the type expected by paramList[i]
    // ideally this would throw if the types were incorrect, but really 
    // any defined behaviour here would be great.
}
```

Is anything like this remotely possible?

Comment: Are you aware of std visit?

Comment: @Yakk, Have read about it, unsure how to go about best using it to solve the problem I have regarding `T ReadValue()` or `void SetValue(T)`  with a variant type. I'm guessing something involving lambda functions and auto return types, but I couldn't work it out.

Comment: Having parsed through some tangentially related links via the C++1z tag, I wonder if moving to a simple Non-Virtual Interface as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3978552/3098505) would work for me. I have only a specific set of types to handle, so having the interface with `void SetParameter(char value) { SetP_Char(value); }` where `virtual void SetP_Char(char c)` is private and overloaded might work. Edit: would probably be ok for `SetV(v)` but won't allow overloading on return for `char GetVal()`...