# C++ refactor common method/logic without polluting interface

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class

- I have an interface:

```
class FooInterface {
  virtual void Method1(bool method) = 0;
};
```

- I have multiple derived classes which implement this interface which all have common logic/method [Method1]:

```
class BarClass1 : FooInterface {
  void Method1(bool method) final {
    if (method) {
      Method2();
    } else {
      Method3();
    }
  }
    void Method2() {// BarClass1 logic};
    void Method3() {// BarClass1 logic};
};

class BarClass2 : FooInterface {
  void Method1(bool method) final {
    if (method) {
      Method2();
    } else {
      Method3();
    }
  }
  void Method2() {// BarClass2 logic};
  void Method3() {// BarClass2 logic};
};
```

- I want to refactor out the common logic without polluting my interface.

Does it make sense to move the common logic into a AbstractClass or is there a more optimal design pattern?

```
class FooAbstractClass : FooInterface {
  void Method1(bool method) final {
    if (method) {
      Method2();
    } else {
      Method3();
    }
  }

  virtual void Method2() = 0;
  virtual void Method3() = 0;
};

class BarClass1 : FooAbstractClass {
    void Method2() final {// BarClass1 logic};
    void Method3() final {// BarClass1 logic};
};

class BarClass2 : FooAbstractClass {
    void Method2() final {// BarClass2 logic};
    void Method3() final {// BarClass2 logic};
};
```

Intended usage:

```
BarClass1 bar1;
bar1.Method1(true);

BarClass2 bar2;
bar2.Method1(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible workaround is to have *another* interface class, for the `Method2` and `Method3` functions. Then create a `BarBase` class which inherits *both* interfaces, but also defines (implements) the `Method1` from `FooInterface`.

Then the two `BarClass1` and `BarClass2` classes inherits `BarBase` and implements `Method2` and `Method3` each in their own way.

Perhaps something like this:

```
struct BarInterface
{
    virtual void Method2() = 0;
    virtual void Method3() = 0;
};

struct BarBase : public FooInterface, public BarInterface
{
    void Method1() override final { /* Call Method2 or Method3... */ }
};

class BarClass1 final : public BarBase
{
public:
    void Method2() override { /* ... */ }
    void Method2() override { /* ... */ }
};

class BarClass2 final : public BarBase
{
public:
    void Method2() override { /* ... */ }
    void Method2() override { /* ... */ }
};
```

This way you can still use pointers to (for example) a `BarClass1` object when passing it to functions wanting a pointer to a `FooInterface`.

As an alternative, if you don't need a separate `BarInterface` you can always declare those functions in the `BarBase` class instead.

Answer (score 1):

One of ways to achieve this is through [private virtual functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970279/what-is-the-point-of-a-private-pure-virtual-function), specifically: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3970378/9171697)

You kind of already do this (i.e. `class` members are by default private) but I do not know if you are just omitting the access modifiers for brevity.

If you the following, then your `Method2` and `Method3` in your interface won't be visible by outside users but may still be overriden by derived classes.

```cpp
class FooInterface {
public:   // Method 1 is public and non-virtual
  void Method1(bool method) {
    if (method) {
        Method2();
    }
    else {
        Method3();
    }
  }
private:  // Method 2 and 3 are private
  virtual void Method2() = 0;
  virtual void Method3() = 0;
};

class BarClass1 : public FooInterface {
private:
    void Method2() final {};
    void Method3() final {};
};
```